# Error occurs using Selenium to logging into WSJ

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a program to automatically log into WSJ.com with my own login. I've looked at some of the other guy's codes, but none of them seemed to have the problem where when click the Login link on the WSJ.com main page, it takes you to two potential pages:

1. Ask for user name and password.
2. Ask for user name, once hit continue brings you to the page mentioned above.

For the 2nd scenario, I have managed to input username and password, then hit login. However that brings me to the next page where it askes if I want to verify my email or continue to WSJ.
In my code, I can't seem to get the webdriver to locate the button that says "Continue to WSJ". If I hit F12 under developer tools, I can locate the button.

Code below:

```py
try:
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@type='button'][@class='solid-button continue-submit new-design']")
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username')))
    user1 = "username"
    pass1 = "password"
    username.send_keys(user1)
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@type='button'][@class='solid-button continue-submit new-design']")
    submit_button.click()
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password')))
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
    username.send_keys(user1)
    password.send_keys(pass1)
    driver.get(url)
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@type='button'][@class='solid-button new-design basic-login-submit']")
    submit_button.click()
except:
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username')))
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
    user1 = "username"
    pass1 = "password"
    username.send_keys(user1)
    password.send_keys(pass1)
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@type='submit'][@class='solid-button basic-login-submit']")
    submit_button.click()
    continue_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "solid-button reg-rtl-btn")))
    continue_button.click()
```

For my code when exception occurs, especially trying to locate the "solid-button reg-rtl-btn" button, it gives me the below message:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".solid-button reg-rtl-btn"}
```

Comment: try solid-button.reg-rtl-btn (dot, not space)

Comment: Thanks man. fixed it, why is this? sorry new to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stringing together classes in a class name selector, they need to get separated by ., which says the next thing coming is also a class name (the first one is automatically a class because you are searching by class).

Thus `solid-button.reg-rtl-btn` will locate by class name and `.solid-button.reg-rtl-btn` would locate by CSS selector, but having the space in between meant it did not know how to interpret `reg-rtl-button`. There are more complicated ways to do this, too, but I do not see why you would want to (maybe if you were worried about the order in which the classes could appear).

Comment: thanks alot. you've saved my day. I have another question, when I succesfully logged in, the page is turned, however when I tried to locate elements, an error occurs, seems can't find the elements. Under site developer mode, the element is on the same page, and I've tried to change browser to the current site and it still not recognize the element. Do you happen to know why? thanks.

Comment: sorry, nothing comes to me off the top of my head on that. I assume you're waiting for it and getting it fresh. Without seeing the html and the locator, it's hard to tell what's missing. It sounds like a new question. I don't have a login to WSJ, so not so simple for me to try it.

Comment: Thanks. I will raise a new question for this one.